# Posting questions about obscure tech if they may not get answers except from official reps

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been working a lot with the [Neural Compute Stick](https://software.intel.com/en-us/movidius-ncs) from Intel Movidius. The technology is fairly recent and pretty obscure as far as I know, and there are only a [handful of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ncsdk?sort=newest) related to it on Stack Overflow.

These Q&A's make me very hesitant to ask for help on Stack Overflow and attempt to make the tag [ncsdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ncsdk) and its related content grow a little bit. Here's why:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52146099/6923568) suggests to post on Intel's forums;
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980785/unexpected-issue-while-building-examples-for-movidius-neural-compute-stick-ncsd) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319823/rpi3-ubuntu-16-04-ncsdk-install-error-no-matching-distribution-found-for-tensorf) question both have a single answer from a user who's presumably from Intel;
- [That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181354/run-ncsdk-movidius-neural-stick-on-macos)'s answer wasn't even related to the tag (just a Docker + MacOS problem).

At this point in time, that's 4 out of 6 questions with that same tag and  topic.

---

**Hesitation**

There is some more activity on the Intel's forum obviously, since that's currently the main source of people who can potentially help (either developers directly, or more active users there). That being said, here's the scenario that leads me to asking this whole question:

1. I post a question on Intel or Movidius forums.
2. Suppose there are replies which aren't quite satisfying, because either the staff doesn't have an answer yet, or a simple lack of visibility leads to it taking a long time.
3. I would like to bring the question to Stack Overflow, but I am hesitant because I'm not sure I want to flood the tag with potentially dead questions OR have replies from Intel after some time, and duplicate content from over that forum.

In an ideal world, I would really like to contribute to that technology's visibility by posting questions on Stack Overflow, and to benefit from the much larger community it has. However I would obviously prefer not to risk posting a lot of dead questions (and likely answers to my own questions).

Should I refrain from posting on that tag/technology and simply keep to to Intel's forums? What are my options?

Comment: Note that a moderator has (rightly) deleted the first answer as it is not an acceptable answer.  A proper SO answer should actually answer the question directly.   That one was at best a comment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of high-quality questions and answers.

If your question is:

- On-topic and generally falls within the rules and guidelines specified in [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).
- Theoretically answerable by another user of the technology (i.e. it's not a support question that can only be answered by the creator)
- Something someone else might also want an answer to at some point

You're encouraged to ask it here.

You could possibly *also* post it to the official forums of the technology, or elsewhere, to increase your chances of getting an answer. You can then post this answer to Stack Overflow to help others.

A few things to keep in mind:

- Having *too few* people see a question is not a big problem for the site as a whole. Yes, you might not get an answer, but the question can't bother all the people who don't even see it. I don't think there's any negative consequence to you personally for asking such questions.
- The only way to expand that community here would be for people to post good questions and answers. Someone has to get that ball rolling.
- Duplicating things here from forums (and elsewhere) isn't a bad thing (as long as you're not plagiarizing). Having information appear in multiple places makes it easier for others to find, and it's generally much easier to find an actual (working) answer to a question asked previously in a Q&A than one asked in a forum.

Comment: Did you copy and paste this from the Help Center? If not, can we please copy and paste it *into* the Help Center?

Comment: Since self-answered questions are okay, and the potential value for future readers matters, it would also be okay to ask a question only you can answer, if there’s a possibility that “another user of the technology” could ask the same question.

Comment: Does SO feel the same way toward those who capture SO content and present it on another web site?

Comment: @lit Yes, as long as you present it in a way that complies with the SO license.

Comment: `The purpose of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of high-quality questions and answers.` - this used to be true, back in the `Jeff Atwood`-days.. but it no longer is.

Comment: @hanshenrik, what would you argue Stack Overflow's purpose is nowadays ?

Comment: @Mat building a repository of answers to every unique programming question under the sun. there is a significant difference.

Comment: *"You can then post this answer to Stack Overflow to help others."*  Details depend on the licensing rules for content in that forum.  Not every forum has an open license on all posted content.

Comment: @hanshenrik Indeed it is different, however I wouldn't think Dukeling's statement and yours are mutually exclusive, in the sense that quantity *shouldn't* lower quality as long as the rules and guidelines are respected/enforced properly.

Comment: @hanshenrik it is my experience that it is more likely for reasonable questions to be closed and downvoted due to them not being useless debugging questions that will never help anyone, than for people to be accepting of "any unique programming question under the sun" as you suggest.

Answer (score 36):

The biggest issue I'm looking at right now is that the people who responded to those posts weren't really posting *answers*.  They were treating this like a help desk in a sense.

That is to say, they were trying to redirect you to their support site and their support forum instead of leveraging Stack Overflow for what it's worth.

So...I would *conjecture* that a question about this technology is fine to ask here, provided that it's an otherwise complete question - e.g. has all of the information contained in it that someone who knows this technology could reasonably answer.

I would also hope that someone from the Community Team does a bit of outreach to Intel.

Comment: I hope so too ! What could we expect from such outreach however ? Has there been similar situations in the past ?

Comment: @Mat See the [tag:outsourcing] tag, with previous instance of companies linking here like SO were their support forum. In this case it seems like the opposite, but it might work as well.

Comment: @llrs I see 0 questions tagged with that, were they all deleted ? If so, I can't see them sadly because low rep.

Comment: @Mat Sorry, the link redirected to the main site, the tag is here in [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outsourcing)

Answer (score 23):

> However I would obviously prefer not to risk posting a lot of dead questions (and likely answers to my own questions).

Isn't that precisely how Stack Overflow works? You ask a question, describing what you are trying to do, and the steps you have taken; then someone (could also be you, 6-8 *somethings* from now) with greater knowledge / experience / patience / time will advance the sum knowledge by providing an answer. Hopefully, your so-called "dead questions" won't remain dead for very long.

Comment: Right, that indeed sounds like the better way to think about it imo. I suppose the current state of the tag was just a bit intimidating haha.

Answer (score 5):

There used to be "too localised" as a close reason, which basically allowed questions to be closed because they were too specific to be part of the greater Stack Overflow archive.

Since 'too specific' is rather subjective, and Stack Overflow doesn't really suffer from all this server space being consumed by specific questions, I think it's good that that close reason was removed ages ago.

That also implies, that if a question is otherwise good, it has a place here on Stack Overflow. And yes, it may remain unanswered for some time, or maybe someone (including yourself) can answer it in a year from now, and it may only help 3 other people, but even then it's still useful.

And even unanswered questions can be useful. Other people having related issues may find your question, and might find an answer to their question in your question. I've had that various times, actually, that I was looking for a way to solve something, and bumped into  a question where the MCVE contained the answer I was looking for.

So don't worry too much. It will have an audience, however small that may be, and like you said, the question can also contribute to the visibility of this new tech that you are enthusiastic about.

Answer (score 2):

I frequently ask questions no one else is asking so I post the question here first, then copy the link into their forum/bug tracker and copy the contents of the question into their forum/bug tracker. They sometimes come here to answer and they sometimes answer in their own forum/bug tracker (in which case I come back here and copy or link their answer).